# Numpy eig/eigh gives negative values for a symmetric positive-semi definite matrix

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

The following code for the CIFAR dataset after GCN:

```
xtx = np.dot(dataset.train_data[i].transpose(), dataset.train_data[i])
e, q = np.linalg.eigh(xtx)
print(np.max(e), np.min(e))
```

Produces the following output:

```
2.65138e+07 -0.00247511
```

This is inconsistent given that `xtx` is symmetric positive-semi definite.  My guess is that this might be due to applying GCN earlier, but still the minimum eigenvalue is not even that close to 0?

Update: So the condition number of my matrix is 8.89952e+09. I've actually have forgotten before to take out the mean so now the maximum eigenvalue is ~573, while the minimum is  -7.14630133e-08. My question is that I'm trying to do ZCA. In this case how should I proceed? Add a diagonal petrubtion to `xtx` or to the Eigenvalues?

Comment: What is the data type of `xtx` (check `xtx.dtype`)?  Is it single precision (`np.float32`)?

Comment: i would say it's pretty close to zero when you consider there are 10 orders of magnitude between the max and min eigenvalue, as @WarrenWeckesser notes this is well within the margin of error for 32 bit float (7-9 digits of precision on average)

Comment: Please post also the result of `numpy.linalg.cond(xtx)`

Comment: @maxymoo, you are assuming that all eigenvalues have the same precision, which of course would depend on how `eigh` works. I doubt this, and tried to find this out quick in the lapack code, but with no success.

Comment: I've updated the questions

Answer (score 0):

If you eigenvalues accross several orders of magnitude you can use the svd decomposition  so that `X.T @ X = (U @ S @ V.T).T @ (U @ S @ V.T) = V @ S @ S @ V.T`.

```py
_, s, v = np.linalg.svd( dataset.train_data[i] )
e = s[:len(v)]**2
```

Now `e` is guaranteed to be positive, and, suppose that you calculated something around `5e3` for the higher singular value and that rounding errors limits the accuracy of the other SVD at `1e-7`, this means that when you calculate `e[1] = s[1]**2` you will actually something at the order of `1e-14`.